# Cast of type 'SEL' to 'SEL' is deprecated; use sel_getName instead

Tags: objective-c, casting

How would you suggest handling this error?  Is the cast necessary in the 
first place?

```
- (NSMethodSignature*)methodSignatureForSelector:(SEL)selector {

  return [dummyStream_ methodSignatureForSelector:(SEL)selector];

}
```

This is the error

> Cast of type 'SEL' to 'SEL' is deprecated; use sel_getName instead

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`selector` is already declared to be of type `SEL`, so the cast is unnecessary.